# Mock Middleware for route testing in Laravel

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, mocking, phpunit, middleware

I am trying to write some unit tests to ensure my routes are not accidentally rewritten. I found already an answer to check whether a correct controller is assigned to particular route [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422426/how-to-test-routes-in-laravel-5-or-trying-to-mockstub-something-or-i-have-no).

However I would like to check as well that correct middlewares are assigned to route. I tried similar approach with

```
$tmp = new CorsService;
$corsMiddleware = Mockery::mock('Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors[handle]', array($tmp))
    ->shouldReceive('handle')->once()
    ->andReturnUsing(function($request, Closure $next) {
        return $next($request);
    });

\App::instance('Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors', $corsMiddleware);
```

For some reason the test is not picking this up. I am assuming that is because middleware instances are not stored using `App::instance`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I have found out there are 2 issues with above code

1. You can not chain `->shouldReceive` directly with return value of `Mockery::mock`
2. there is missing `\` from Closure

Working example:

```
$tmp = new CorsService;
$corsMiddleware = Mockery::mock('Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors[handle]', array($tmp));
$corsMiddleware->shouldReceive('handle')->once()
    ->andReturnUsing(function($request, \Closure $next) {
        return $next($request);
    });

\App::instance('Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors', $corsMiddleware);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to to use `->getMock()` at the end, if you are going to chain things like `->shouldReceive` directly to your Mock object:

```
$corsMiddleware = Mockery::mock('Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors[handle]', array($tmp))
    ->shouldReceive('handle')->once()
    ->andReturnUsing(function($request, Closure $next) {
        return $next($request);
    })
    ->getMock();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get routes and check their middlewares

```
// Get Routes
    foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
        $middleware = $route->gatherMiddleware();
        $name = $route->getName();
        \Log::debug($name.'--');
        \Log::debug($middleware);
    }
```